# use RenderMvcController to filter a list in Umbraco

Tags: ajax, filter, umbraco7, asp.net-mvc-controller, surface-controller

my goal is to create a list of contents (of specific docType) . in this list I have a filter button and two ddlist dynamically filled with children data. when user click the "filter" , the list should be updated by selected ddlist values.
Is it possible to use **RenderMVCController** for this ? I couldnt used **surfaceController** because I cant have access to Index action before rendering the page.
Is it possible to use Ajax when user submit the form instead of refreshing all page?

***View***

```
using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("FilterPage", "inTheFieldController", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "PageInTheField" }))
{
//....
}
```

***Controller***

```
public class inTheFieldController : RenderMvcController
{

    private readonly UmbracoContext umbracoContext;

    public inTheFieldController()
    {
        umbracoContext = UmbracoContext.Current;
    }


    // GET: inTheField
    public ActionResult Index()//RenderModel model)
    {
}
```

and I want to have something like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult FilterPage(inTheFieldModel model)
  {
    return null
     }
```

But it never reached to this point,it asks for *surfaceController*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use the BeginUmbracoForm it will always expect a SurfaceController. Ideally you should be using SurfaceController for forms. I dont clearly understand what you are trying to do here but you can use @Ajax.BeginForm and couple it with a SurfaceController action

Comment: If I use SurfaceControllers , how can I fill ddlist ? I need have Index before rendering the page. Is it possible with surface controllers?

Comment: create a view model with a list and return that view model from the index action